# PhP Question on n-dimensional arrays - Bob the Robot goes shopping?

Tags: php, arrays

Bob the robot goes shopping and is controlled by your new php course study app.

One of the exercises is testing your understanding of multi-dimensional arrays.

Bob the robot takes orders through echo statements that tell him which items you want to buy, once he arrives at the hardware store.

The code he has access to reads as follows:

```
<?php
$cleaning = array('limescale remover','duster','broom','drain unblocker','bleach spray');
$gardening = array('spade','weedkiller','carrot seeds','rake', 'sprinkler','garden fencing');
$tools = array('hammer', 'screwdriver set', 'spanners', 'cordless drill', 'box of nails');
$store_items = array(
$cleaning,
$gardening,
$tools
);

?>
```

Your shopping list reads:

- 1 x box of nails
- 1 x hammer
- 1 x broom
- 1 x garden fencing

He can only buy these if you send him the commands via echo statements,  to 'pick out' these items from this store. For example:

```
echo $store_items[?][?]
```

provide the four echo statements that will enable Bob to get your items from the store.

good luck!

Comment: Your arrays have different lengths, 5-6-5, your output values haven't any depending. So, you haven't any issue cause you didn't clarified the input conditions and input data at all. You need to define depending between values.

Comment: Did you try `print_r($store_items);`? That should make it pretty obvious what the `echo` statements need to be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Comment: This is a terribly written problem.  Bob has access to code?  How does he run it?  How can you echo code that Bob has?  Sounds out of scope to me.  More appropriate to have Bob as a server app, and some api for you to order items from Bob.

Comment: Chris this is not homework bro, im 41 yrs old : ))
I was just posting this to allow 'younger newbies' on here to have something to answer, easy question for them that was all :-)

do i need to explain my own question and answer now ? : ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you need to understand that you have an array of arrays. Each item of `$store_items` is an array of its own, the first item has the index of 0, the second has an index of 1 and the third has the index of two. The indexes are in the order the items were added. The inner arrays are arrays of string values, indexed in a similar way, so the solution is:

```
echo $store_items[2][4];
echo $store_items[2][0];
echo $store_items[0][4];
echo $store_items[1][5];
```

Comment: Correct thats right - i posted this question because instead of declaring those inner arrays inside the parent array, i declared them outside and then placed their variable names inside and tested it out.  It worked well, just something i learned. I'm guessing your answer is correct so I wont  check it :-)